# What does the “missing separator” error in a Makefile mean?

Tags: c, makefile

Below is my output from the command `command cat -e -t -v makefile_name`.
The indentation looks correct to me.

```
:shell_project cam$ cat -e -t -v Makefile
CC = gcc$
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall$
$
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myshell myshell.o$
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myshell.c$
$
myshell.o:  myshell.c #myshell.h$
^I$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myshell.c$
$
clean:$
^I$(RM) myshell *.o *~$
$
$(MAKE) -C ./processe$
```

But when I invoke `make`, I am getting the error

> ```
>  Makefile:4 *** missing separator. Stop
> ```

Comment: Line 4, 5 and 13 are commands to execute, but `target: [...]` or `VAR = ...` is expected

Comment: The “4” in “Makefile:4” means line 4. Line 4 is `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myshell myshell.o`. That is just a bare command. Commands should be indented and appear after a rule starting with a target.

Answer (score 2):

The `4` in `Makefile:4` means line 4.

Line 4, 5 and 13 are commands to execute, but `target: [...]` or `VAR = ...` is expected. I believe you want the following:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all: myshell

myshell: myshell.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myshell myshell.o

myshell.o: myshell.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myshell.c

clean:
    $(RM) myshell myshell.o *~
```

With implicit rules, this can be simplified to

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all: myshell

myshell: myshell.o

myshell.o: myshell.c

clean:
    $(RM) myshell myshell.o *~
```

(I don't know what line 13 is supposed to do, so it's not present in this fixed make file.)

(Tabs are replaced with spaces by SO in the rendering. You will need to adjust this if you copy either of the above make files.)

Comment: With implicit rules you don’t need the `myshell.o` rule either.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, If you don't include `myshell: myshell.o`, `myshell.o` will get deleted automatically, so it wouldn't be equivalent. Also, it looks like the OP might be intending to add a dependency on `myshell.h`, which would require the rule.